# oubleSpinBox Displayed value not correct

Tags: double, pyqt4

i have a spinbox like:

```
input = QDoubleSpinBox()
input.value = 0.02
```

In the gui, it shows:

> 2.00

But i like that it shows

> 0.02

how should i do?

Comment: `input.setValue(0.02)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like that it shows `0.02`

You will probably need to set the precision of the step in decimal places

for example: `setSingleStep (0.02)`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, 
                             QVBoxLayout, QDoubleSpinBox)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    
        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        vBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Current Value", self)
        self.label.move(60, 60)
        vBoxLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.spinBox = QDoubleSpinBox(self)  
        self.spinBox.move(60, 30)
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(0)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(12)
        self.spinBox.setSingleStep(0.02)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)

    def valueChanged(self):
        self.label.setText("Current Value  {:.2f}".format(self.spinBox.value()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aplicacion = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 220, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(aplicacion.exec_())
```

[image]